# search key in php

Tags: php

I would like to search a key of an array in php which contains the word.

Example :

```
$test = array("hello"=>"value1","hello5"=>"value","testinghello"=>"test");
```

I would like to use it like this.

```
if(!empty($test[key_here_which_contains_hello]))
```

I would like to display the value of an array with the key contains hello. In that example all value will be displayed because all keys has "hello".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($test as $key => $val) {
    if (strpos($key, 'hello') !== false) {
        print $val."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `strpos` function like this :

```
foreach($test as $key=>$value){
   if(strpos($key,'helo')){
      echo $value;
   }
}
```

Comment: strpos expects haystack, then needle

Answer (score 1):

```
$test = array("hello"=>"value1","hello5"=>"value","testinghello"=>"test");
$keys = array_keys( $test );
$searchkey = array_search( 'hello', $keys, true );
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP got the function [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).
I'm thinking thats what your looking for:

```
<?php
$search_array = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 4);

if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) {
    echo $search_array['first'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be done by

```
foreach($test as $key=>$value){
   if(strpos('hello',$key)){
      echo $value;
   }
}
```

or

```
if (array_key_exists('hello', $test)) { //array_key_exists ( $key , array $search )
    echo "hello";
}
```